# TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'long' in Python

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, typeerror, unary-operator

I am from a C background and hence this problem in Python really confounds me

Consider this

```
print ~(1 << 1)
```

This correctly prints `-3`.

Consider this

```
print ~(1 << 0)
```

This flags an error like

```
TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'long'
```

I checked for various other positive values of shift count and it works fine. Only a shift count of zero doesn't seem to work. All similar posts on unary operators that I found on SO dealt with other operators like `+`, `-` etc but not `~`

I just dabble in Python every now and then, so I may be missing something silly but googling dint help much

PS: I ran this on [codeskulptor](http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user38_nfYgexfzeb_0.py) which is probably using Python 2.7, I am not sure though

**EDIT**: This turns out to be a bug in Codeskulptor. I wrote a mail to Prof Rixner who's the main developer to take note of this bug. Thanks all.

Comment: Works for me (2.7.6). What version of python are you using?

Comment: Also, print ~(1 << 1) is syntactically wrong in Python 3.0 and above. `print (~(1 << 1))` prints -3. Works for me on Python 3.3. I have also run it on IDEONE [here](http://ideone.com/RTfUcf)

Comment: @hagubear: The question is flagged with [Python], not [Python3].

Comment: @EthanFurman It wasn't tagged [python2] either, so no version should be assumed unless explicitly mentioned in the question. [python] is about both versions.

Comment: This worked for me in CPython, Jython, IronPython, and PyPy (2.X branches), so you must be in a very strange environment.

Comment: Worked for me on 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, and 2.7.

Comment: python 2 it works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an error with CodeSkulptor's implementation.

If you force the value back to int, it works:

```
print ~(int(1 << 0))
```

---

Okay, perhaps 'error' was too strong -- looking at their site they only claim to "implement a subset of Python 2".

Comment: Implementation of print()? You mean it was overridden?

Comment: @hagubear: No, not print, but CodeSkulptor's Python implementation does work correctly with the `long` type, at least with the `~` operator.

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion of forcing it to `int` works on codeskulptor. I shall go with your modiffication and leave the bug to the codeskulptor's devs :)

Answer (score 0):

This works in both Python2 and Python3; to demonstrate:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.6
$ python -c 'print(~(1<<0))'
-2

$ python3 --version
Python 3.4.2
$ python3 -c 'print(~(1<<0))'
-2
```

Can you show a bit more of your script and explain which version (and which implementation!) of Python you're using?